# What is causing "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation" in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Google Chrome's console is telling me

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation

when the following function is invoked

```
   $('#txtUploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                    data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    xhr: function() {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                                console.log("percentComplete = " + percentComplete);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("lengthComputable evaluated to false;")
                            }
                        }, false);

                        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                                console.log("percentComplete = " + percentComplete);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("lengthComputable evaluated to false;")
                            }
                        }, false);

                        return xhr;
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("upload","FileUploadAsync")',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("success!");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
            }
        }
    });
```

I've looked through StackOverflow posts on this issue and none of the causes relate to anything I can see in mine. I'm not sure if it matters, but I can post  the HTML and the controller if that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Have you narrowed down to WHERE in all that code the error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two options for the `$.ajax` call, these

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

Making it like this

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                console.log("percentComplete = " + percentComplete);
            } else {
                console.log("lengthComputable evaluated to false;")
            }
        }, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                console.log("percentComplete = " + percentComplete);
            } else {
                console.log("lengthComputable evaluated to false;")
            }
        }, false);

        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("upload","FileUploadAsync")',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success!");
    }
});
```

if you let jQuery process the files internally it throws an `Illegal invocation` error.

Comment: The specific error thrown is because jQuery saves data.append as a reference, and tries to call that reference as a function later, and Chrome wouldn't let that happen.

Comment: @PawelVeselov - Actually it's jQuery's `$.param` that throws the error because it's trying to *"Serialize an array of form elements or a set of key/values into a query string"*, which doesn't work very well with files.

Comment: my bad. `$.param()` treats data as an object, trying to extract key/value pairs from it, then it finds keys that are functions, and treats those as functions that would produce data, calling them, and without `this` context. `FormData` implementation doesn't like that.